# Enable/Disable Next Button

Tags: javascript

I have a form where I save first and last name in the localstore.

If the name and surname are filled, I enable the button and if not, it remains disabled.

How do I get this validation to run in real time, on each change made by the user, at the moment I have this
Next

```
const name = localStorage.getItem('name'); 
const last_name = localStorage.getItem('last_name'); 
                  
if(name === null || last_name === null ) {
   document.getElementById("continue_button").disabled = true; 
}else{
   document.getElementById("continue_button").disabled = false;
}
```

Comment: Add eventlisteners to the input and use the [change even](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/change_event) or [input event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/input_event) to call a function, which checks, if the button should be enabled or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a very short way of doing it:

```js
const [btn,...inps]=["continue_button","name","last_name"].map(n=>document.getElementById(n));
inps.forEach(el=>el.addEventListener("input",ev=>btn.disabled=inps.some(inp=>inp.value.trim()=="")))
```

```html
<input type="text" id="name" placeholder="first name">
<input type="text" id="last_name" placeholder="last name">
<button id="continue_button" disabled>go</button>
```

The `.map()` in the first line of code collects the DOM elements, as specified by their `id` attributes, and packs them into the constants `btn` (the first returned value) and `inps` (all other returned values).

In the second line the event-listener for the "input" event is added to all elements of `inps`. The attached listener function then checks whether it can find at least one element of the `inps` array having a trimmed `.value` attribute of `""`. If so, the button's `disabled` attribute will be set to `true`, otherwise to `false`.

Answer (score 0):

You can add event listener to the input fields themselves to check if there is any change.

```
const nameInput = document.getElementById("name");
const lastnameInput = document.getElementById("last_name");

nameInput.addEventListener("input", () => {
  const name = nameInput.value;
  const lastname = lastnameInput.value;

  if (name !== null && lastname !== null) {
    document.getElementById("continue_button").disabled = false;
  } else {
    document.getElementById("continue_button").disabled = true;
  }
});

lastnameInput.addEventListener("input", () => {
  const name = nameInput.value;
  const lastname = lastnameInput.value;

  if (name !== null && lastname !== null) {
    document.getElementById("continue_button").disabled = false;
  } else {
    document.getElementById("continue_button").disabled = true;
  }
});
```

Comment: I didn't manage to implement your solution, could you help here by executing code snippet please